# xml declaration not being omitted from page

Tags: xml, xslt, asp.net

I have an XSLT transform I am using to process an XML file, inserting it into the body of my aspx page.

Reference the following for background information:

[background on xml/xslt](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_output.asp)

I have the following in my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    xmlns:myCustomStrings="urn:customStrings">
  <xsl:output
    method="xml" version="2.0"
    media-type="text/html"
    omit-xml-declaration="yes"
    indent="yes"
 />...unrelated stuff left out here
```

Here is the output that is relevent:

```
<div id="example" />
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><div xmlns:myCustomStrings="urn:customStrings"><div id="imFormBody" class="imFormBody">
```

My question relates to the output, specifically to the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` which is getting included in the output anyway.  Is the issue related to the custom method I have used?  If so, I don't really see the need to include the xml part as the namespace is in the div tag.  Is there a way to ensure that this extra stuff gets left out as I asked it to?

transform code: yeah, its ugly but I am prototyping some stuff :)

```
public static string SmartNotePageFromTemplate(string patientVisitId, string followupType, bool copyPreviousNote)
    {
        // create custom object
        CustomStrings customStrings = new CustomStrings();//specify class for use in XSLT

        string noteXmlFile = ImSmartNotesConfig.GetSmartNotesXmlFile();//get xml data file name from config
        string noteXslFile = ImSmartNotesConfig.GetSmartNotesXsltFile();// get xslt file name from config

        string subXmlFile = "../SmartNotesXml/testData.xml";
        string subCSSFile = "../CSS/testCSS.css";
        string subJSFile = "../Js/testJS.js";

        try
        {
            XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings(true, true);// allow the document() in the xslt

            XsltArgumentList xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();// create argument list for xslt
            xslArg.AddParam("subXmlFile", "", subXmlFile);
            xslArg.AddParam("subCSSFile", "", subCSSFile);
            xslArg.AddParam("subJSFile", "", subJSFile);
            //pass an instance of the custom object
            xslArg.AddExtensionObject("urn:customStrings", customStrings);

            XslCompiledTransform myXslt = new XslCompiledTransform(true);// we will use the compiled xslt processor
            myXslt.Load(noteXslFile, settings, new XmlUrlResolver());// load the xslt in
            StringWriter stWrite = new StringWriter();// create output writer

            //myXslt.Transform(noteXmlFile, xslArg, stWrite);// transform 
            SmartNote.BL.SmartNoteLogic logic = new SmartNote.BL.SmartNoteLogic();
            XmlDocument noteXml = logic.GetNewNoteXml(patientVisitId, followupType, copyPreviousNote);
            myXslt.Transform(noteXml, xslArg, stWrite);// transform 

            return stWrite.ToString();// put the StringWriter as a string to the output- html page in this instance, as used in the .aspx.cs file
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code performing the transformation would be useful.

Comment: (For instance, if you end up loading your output into an XmlDocument and do an OuterXml on it, it doesn't matter what your omit-xml-declaration says)

Comment: Added the transform code

Comment: I think more context is still needed. I have no problem on test code (using yours as a base) in keeping the XML declaration off. When using a StringWriter, it uses UTF-16 encoding, so if the transform/writer were applying an XML declaration, it would show UTF-16 in the encoding attribute (as it does when I specify "no" for "omit-xml-declaration"). There is something else somewhere in your code I think and more context is necessary (things you consider irrelevant may not be so).

Comment: In `xml:output`, shouldn't `version="2.0"` be `version="1.0"` instead? The method is `xml`, but there is no XML 2.0.

Comment: It makes no difference really, it seems to get ignored either way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turns out this was as a result of the method server side where I did the transform.

It did not matter what the XSLT said as the .net method overrode that.

I ended up with the following code snip in my c# code:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
```